# How to set the optional parameter , "use_local_topics", of joint_state_broadcaster of ros2_control (foxy)

Tags: ros2, ros-foxy, joint-trajectory-controller, ros2-control, ros2-controllers

I'm using ros2 control foxy now,and I'm trying to define namespace for my robot. The problem is that joint_state_broadcaster doesn't publish the /joint_states to the local topic /ns/joint_states. According to this [Link](https://control.ros.org/foxy/doc/ros2_controllers/joint_state_broadcaster/doc/userdoc.html), it seems like we can change the parameter use_local_topics to 'true' for using our own namespace. Have someone tried this, i'm not sure the place that I should edit. In my understanding, should be somewhere in config file. Here is my config file, but it doesn't work.

```
# Controller manager configuration
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 200 # Hz

    ### Controllers available
    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster
      use_local_topics: true

    forward_position_controller:
      type: forward_command_controller/ForwardCommandController

    position_trajectory_controller:
      type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController



### Properties of the controllers that we will use and definition of joints to use ###
forward_position_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - j1
      - j2
      - j3

    interface_name: position


position_trajectory_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - j1
      - j2
      - j3


    command_interfaces:
      - position

    state_interfaces:
      - position
      

    state_publish_rate: 50.0 # Hz, Defaults to 50
    action_monitor_rate: 20.0 # Hz, Defaults to 20

    allow_partial_joints_goal: false # Defaults to false
    open_loop_control: false
    allow_integration_in_goal_trajectories: true
    constraints:
      stopped_velocity_tolerance: 0.01 # Defaults to 0.01
      goal_time: 0.0 # Defaults to 0.0 (start immediately)

    gain:
      j1:
        p: 100.0
        i: 10.0
        d: 3600.0
      
      j2:
        p: 100.0
        i: 10.0
        d: 3600.0

      j3:
        p: 100.0
        i: 10.0
        d: 3600.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare parameters for the controllers in an own top-level section instead inside the controller_manager

```
joint_state_broadcaster:
  ros__parameters:
    use_local_topics: true
```

Comment: Hi!, thank you for your answer, I edited the code but the joint_state_broadcaster still cannot publish /joint_state to my local topic /ns/topics for some reason. For this problem, do you have any suggestion that I should fix?

Comment: It should be sent to `joint_state_broadcaster/joint_states` instead of `/joint_states`?
How do you check which topics it published to?

Comment: Oh yes, I check by rqt_graph and it send to { joint_state_broadcaster/joint_states }. But can we define the workspace for that? Like want to make 2 launch files that connected to 2 robots using ros2_control. So I'm trying to define namespace for each of them. Let say, {/ns1/robot_state_publisher} and {/ns2/robot_state_publisher} which should subscribe to {/ns1/joint_states} and {/ns2/joint_states}. Is my idea correct?

Comment: you can try to add a namespace to the ros2_control_node (if you use it, or how do you launch the controller manager?), but I'm not sure now if this is propagated to the loaded controllers, too.

Comment: it should, have a look at this [demo (WIP)](https://github.com/StoglRobotics-forks/ros2_control_demos/pull/8)

Comment: Yes, I use ros2_control_node. [here](https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#hlpgty3i2k8r1qv4y48qjr) is my launch file that I'm using now. I add the ns to that node, but it was not working and I cannot see /joints_state/broadcaster in my rqt_graph. I'm not sure that I did somewhere wrong or not.....

Comment: have a look at [this](https://github.com/StoglRobotics-forks/ros2_control_demos/blob/11e2c886e5bf3fe3d1c3ce42b8b21a2f9f4c0aad/ros2_control_demo_bringup/launch/rrbot_namespace.launch.py) launch file. you have to add the namespace to the Node argument, but also use the same namespace for the spawners (not as argument, but to set the correct service name of the controller manager)

Comment: Oh, thank you so much for your help! Now it's solved. So, I fixed the .yaml file that you need to also add the namespace tag to the controller. Refer to this [github](https://github.com/StoglRobotics-forks/ros2_control_demos/blob/11e2c886e5bf3fe3d1c3ce42b8b21a2f9f4c0aad/ros2_control_demo_bringup/config/rrbot_namespace_controllers.yaml)